# PowerBI retain context/filters on CALCULATETABLE

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a simple sample of my rather complex conundrum. I have a table with customer Name, Surname, Category and Colour.

I want to make a calculated table off of the same customers table, but want to retain all filters on that customers table.

I have set my CALCULATED table out as follows:

```
CalcdCustomers = SELECTCOLUMNS(ALL(Customers), "Name", Customers[Name], "Surname", Customers[Surname], "MyOtherColumn", "SomeMeasureOrCalc")
```

But when I filter customers, the calculated table does not filter.

[image]

Is it possible to have the filters applied to Customers propagate to my calculated table. In the case of my example. I only want Name1, Name2 and Name10 to reflect in the calculated table (as driven by the filter on Customers).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created a table using CALCULATETABLE, you essentially added a new table to your data model. If you want filters in one table to propagate to this new table you're going to have to add a relationship between the tables.

Comment: I've done that - but was hoping for some PowerBI sugar.

Comment: That would be nice I guess but difficult for DAX to figure out how you might want the tables joined. Fortunately you only have to create this relationship once and not each time the data model is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

A calculated table in your data model cannot be dynamically responsive to slicers since it is only computed once. You can use calculated tables within a measure (though the final output of the measure will still have to be a scalar).

---

Note: I think you may want to reconsider if you actually need a calculated table. I can't think of many reasons for using one that don't have reasonable workarounds.